# How to remove white background of an image - java

Tags: java, image

I would like to remove white background of an image and save it as another image.
I have wrote a code which extracts the background but it leaves some of the pixel value.
Checkout original Image : [image]

Checkout cropped image : [image]

It still leaves some amount of white background.

I want to remove that also.

Here is my code :

```
       int x1=0;
    int y1=0;
    boolean res = false;
    System.out.println("in formatImage");
```

//Widht Removal...

```
  for (int x = 0; x <= w-1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= h-1; y++) {
                if(new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, y)).getRGB()==-1)
                {res=false;}
                else if (!new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, y)).equals(Color.WHITE)) {
                    res = true;
                }
                if (res) {
                    for (int p = y; p <= h-1; p++) {
                        b21.setRGB(x1,p,new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, p)).getRGB());                        
                    }
                    x1++;
                    res = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        b21=new BufferedImage(x1,h,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        x1=0;
        for (int x = 0; x <= w-1; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y <= h-1; y++) {
                if(new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, y)).getRGB()==-1)
                {res=false;}
                else if (!new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, y)).equals(Color.WHITE)) {
                    res = true;
                }
                if (res) {
                    for (int p = 0; p <= h-1; p++) {
                        b21.setRGB(x1,p,new Color(bi1.getRGB(x, p)).getRGB());
                    }
                    x1++;
                    res = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

//Height Removal

```
for (int y = 0; y <= h-1; y++) {
    System.out.println("Y = "+y);
    for (int x = 0; x <= x1-1; x++) {
        System.out.println("("+x+","+y+") : "+b21.getRGB(x, y));
        if (!new Color(b21.getRGB(x, y)).equals(Color.WHITE)) {
            res = true;
        }
        if (res) {
            for (int p = 0; p <= x1-1; p++) {
               b31.setRGB(p,y1,new Color(b21.getRGB(p, y)).getRGB());

            }
            y1++;
            res = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
b31=new BufferedImage(x1,y1,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
int ty=y1;
y1=0;
for (int y = 0; y <= h-1; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x <= x1-1; x++) {
        if (!new Color(b21.getRGB(x, y)).equals(Color.WHITE)) {
            res = true;
        }
        if (res) {
            for (int p = 0; p <= x1-1; p++) {
               b31.setRGB(p,y1,new Color(b21.getRGB(p, y)).getRGB());
            }
            y1++;
            res = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

b31 has final image.

Comment: What do you mean by "remove white background"?  Are you really asking how to ***crop*** the image? That seems to be what your code does.  What is not working? What part of the white background is not being removed? Your question is unclear.

Comment: the background near hand is not getting removed. You can check the same by downloading image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Jim said,
the colour near body are not pure white.
So you modify the following statement of your code & it will work great for you.
Replace following command line

```
if (!new Color(b21.getRGB(x, y)).equals(Color.WHITE))
```

by

```
 if (new Color(b21.getRGB(x, y)).getRGB()<-1000000)
```

This will give you  the output which you want.
You can vary the shades of white & gray from -1000000 to -2000000

Answer (score 2):

If you examine the image with any decent image editor you will find that pixels near the model's head, left hand and right elbow are not pure white (0xFFFFFF).

[image]

You need to adjust your algorithm to allow some slight deviation from full intensity on all 3 channels.  It's up to you to decide how much leeway to allow.

Answer (score 0):

I did create a function to convert white background to transparent

```
    public Image makeWhiteBGToTransparent(final BufferedImage im) {
    final ImageFilter filter = new RGBImageFilter() {
        public int markerRGB = 0xFFFFFFFF;

        public final int filterRGB(final int x, final int y, final int rgb) {
            if ((rgb | 0xFF000000) == markerRGB) {
                return 0x00FFFFFF & rgb;
            } else {
                return rgb;
            }
        }
    };

    final ImageProducer ip = new FilteredImageSource(im.getSource(), filter);
    return Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(ip);
}
```

Now, if we want to convert this `Image` to `BufferedImage` then use this function

```
public BufferedImage toBufferedImage(Image img) {
    if (img instanceof BufferedImage) {
        return (BufferedImage) img;
    }

    BufferedImage bImage = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null),
            BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D bGr = bImage.createGraphics();
    bGr.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
    bGr.dispose();
    return bImage;
}
```